# How to change size of barcode img generated by barcode4j on primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, barcode

i'm using primefaces to generated some barcodes (in cod128 format), the primefaces tags works pretty well but the client want the output image (with the codes) at some specific size (1cm of height and 8cm of width), so that's the question:

How i can show a fixed output of the generated barcode at some specific size?

Here is some snippet of my code:

```
<h:body>
    <p:panelGrid columns="2">

    <h:outputText value="Code128" />
    <p:barcode value="0123456789" type="code128"/>

</p:panelGrid>
</h:body>
```

i'm using this for reference: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/multimedia/barcode.xhtml

Thanks :)

Comment: Couldn't you use the tag attributes `width` and `height` ?

Comment: yes indeed, that's a solution, thx :)

Comment: You're welcome, that's the _default_ solution ;)

Comment: @omar: please create this as an answer

Comment: @Kukeltje, okay.

Comment: This does not change the proportions .

Comment: Indeed, the question is about the size, i don't know if you can use some to display i.e. at 160%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primefaces tag allows you to change the width and height of the component:

```
<p:barcode value="0123456789" type="code128" width="Xpx;" height="Ypx;"/>
```

since the size you need is "cm", I would suggest you look for a converter on the web.

Answer (score 1):

You can control and fix the output's size by using the dimensions' attributes of `<p:barcode>`'s tag, so that you don't need extra CSS/JS improvements :

```
<p:barcode value="0123456789" type="code128" height="38px" width="302px" />
```

Comment: This does not resize the barcode. IT only changes the size, but the proportion is not changed. Barcode height is too much and not not control with this attributes.